# Where to place email validator within project?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am on day 2 of learning node and Java Script. I have been following basic tutorials and decided to attempt and implement simple email validation into my code.

The problem is i am not sure where to place the code - i have a server.js file that holds all of the CRUD operations and a Mongoose model that which ensures the correct data is entered. Does anyone have any advice as to the best way to validate a user-entered email using this module?

```
 //Email-validation npm module
 var validator = require("email-validator");

 validator.validate("test@email.com");


 //Mongoose model
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var Tickets = new Schema({

   name: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   },
   email: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   },
   address: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   },
   price: {
     type: Number,
     required: true,
     min: 1,
     max: 100
   }

 });

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Ticket', TicketSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate email before saving object. Code should look something like this:

```
Tickets.pre('save', function (next) {
var ticket = this;
if (!ticket.isModified('email')) {
    next();
} else {
    var valid = validator.validate(ticket.email);
    if(valid) {
        next();
    } else {
        next(valid);
    }        
}
});
```